# SpecFlow .feature.cs file gets duplicated when feature file is edited

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, specflow

When I edit `Foo.feature`, SpecFlow creates a new `Foo1.feature.cs` instead of overwriting `Foo.feature.cs`. The duplicated file then causes compile errors due to duplicated symbols.

It happens only for one of the .feature files in my project - all others behave normally. All the .feature and .feature.cs files are under source control and added to the `Foo.csproj` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the problem - in my .csproj file I had this entry:

```
<None Include="Foo.feature">
  <Generator>SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Foo1.feature.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

I think the `<LastGenOutput>` was confusing SpecFlow. I don't know where it came from, but changing it to `<LastGenOutput>Foo.feature.cs</LastGenOutput>` fixed the issue.

**Edit:** I just found out that a missing `<LastGenOutput>` tag can also cause a duplicate `Foo1.feature.cs` file to be created. So if the tag is missing create it and put the correct filename in it.

After googling for SpecFlow and "LastGenOutput", I found this thread - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specflow/SpOihmvoAOQ. It outlines the same problem and solution:

> Issue may be very annoying. Possible solution (do at you own risk!)
>
> 1. delete all YourFeature1.feature.cs files in Visual Studio. Save project.
> 2. close Visual Studio, open your .csproj file with notepad
> 3. find the lines similar to this one:
>
> YourFeature1.feature.cs
>
> change them to
>
> YourFeature.feature.cs
>
> save, load project in Visual Studio. Enjoy.

But you have to already know the solution in order to find that thread.

Comment: I've had this problem before caused by copying .feature files. This fixed it for me.